# Movie about zombie vampires

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

This seemed more or less like a typical zombie action movie. However, the zombies are actually later revealed to be zombie vampires later on. Unlike the regular movie zombies, their head has to be completely destroyed to kill them; a simple headshot will not work. Thus, the weapons of choice for the survivors tend to be large-caliber guns (maybe .50 cals?). Among the group of survivors in the film are regular humans and some vampires, though said vampires are not hostile towards humans, but they do burn in the sunlight (which is how the humans realize who they are). I think one of them is named Dragon or Drakon, some variation of that name. He reveals that the vampires are used to drinking cow blood and that the zombie outbreak came about when a virus called "cow rabies" (that's a direct translation of the wording the Russian dub used) mutated and created the zombie vampires.

Can anyone identify the movie?

Comment: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0923653/?

Answer (score 15):

Could this be *[The Dead Undead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0923653/)* (2010)?

Good vampires join forces with a group of humans to fight against zombie vampires.

> A group of peaceful Vampires are infected and turned into crazed zombie like creatures whose only motivation is to feed on flesh, whether Human or Vampire. A group of Vampire commandos tries to keep their identity secret, while trying to stop the spread of the infection. Soldiers from across the ages, it's up to these vampires to end the zombie infection. Caught in the middle is a group of human kids on a camping trip, who team up with the Vampires in an attempt to survive.

Comment: The cast _is_ literally comprised of characters named “Zombie Vampire.” Lol!